# Graph point on straight line (number line) in Python

Tags: python, graph, charts, matplotlib

Trying to figure out what's the best way to graph a  point on a number line in python. Essentially trying to make something similar to the image below:

[image: Point on a number line]

I've been trying to use Matplotlib to do this but can't seem to figure it out. Anyone know of a package or anything out there I can use?

Comment: What have you tried?  It looks like what you want should be pretty easy using mpl.

Comment: Can you point me to an example? I've tried turning off the y-axis, but I still get a square chart. And when I try to add vertical lines at the end, they still span the whole square,

Answer (score 13):

I don't know of a specific package for this but you could do something like this in Matplotlib using [hlines](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.hlines), [vlines](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.vlines) and [plot](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.plot).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# set up the figure
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.set_xlim(0,10)
ax.set_ylim(0,10)

# draw lines
xmin = 1
xmax = 9
y = 5
height = 1

plt.hlines(y, xmin, xmax)
plt.vlines(xmin, y - height / 2., y + height / 2.)
plt.vlines(xmax, y - height / 2., y + height / 2.)

# draw a point on the line
px = 4
plt.plot(px,y, 'ro', ms = 15, mfc = 'r')

# add an arrow
plt.annotate('Price five days ago', (px,y), xytext = (px - 1, y + 1), 
              arrowprops=dict(facecolor='black', shrink=0.1), 
              horizontalalignment='right')

# add numbers
plt.text(xmin - 0.1, y, '80', horizontalalignment='right')
plt.text(xmax + 0.1, y, '115', horizontalalignment='left')

plt.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: The line in the middle is exactly what I'm looking for, but is there any way I can get rid of everything around it? I'm trying to build this out so that I can implement into a script that auto-saves the images and then displays them on a webpage.

Comment: You can use plt.axis('off') to turn off the axis. See my edit.

Answer (score 6):

Here ya go, official example from matplotlib, including example code and everything. To plot a labeled point on the line, just do a [normal scatterplot](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.scatter.html) with the y coordinates being 0:

https://matplotlib.org/examples/ticks_and_spines/tick-locators.html

[image]

Comment: For those looking for the newest documentation, it is here: https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/ticks/tick-formatters.html