# scikits learn SVM - 1-dimensional Separating Hyperplane

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scikit-learn, svm

How to plot the separating "hyperplane" for 1-dimensional data using scikit svm ?

I follow this guide for 2-dimensional data : http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/svm/plot_svm_margin.html, but don't know how to make it works for 1-dimensional data

```
pos = np.random.randn(20, 1) + 1
neg = np.random.randn(20, 1) - 1
X = np.r_[pos, neg]
Y = [0] * 20 + [1] * 20
clf = svm.SVC(kernel='linear', C=0.05)
clf.fit(X, Y)

# how to get "hyperplane" and margins values ??
```

thanks

Answer (score 6):

The separating hyperplane for two-dimensional data is a line, whereas for one-dimensional data the hyperplane boils down to a point. The easiest way to plot the separating hyperplane for one-dimensional data is a bit of a hack: the **data are made two-dimensional** by adding a second feature which takes the value 0 for all the samples. By doing so, the second component of the weight vector is zero, i.e. **w** = [*w<sub>0</sub>*, 0] (see the appendix at the end of this post). As *w<sub>1</sub>* = 0 and *w<sub>1</sub>* is in the denominator of the expression that defines the slope and the y-intercept term of the separating line (see appendix), both coefficients are ∞. In this case it is convenient to solve the equation of the separating hyperplane for *x*, which results in *x* = *x<sub>0</sub>* = -b/*w<sub>0</sub>*. The margin turns out to be 2/*w<sub>0</sub>* (see appendix for details).

The following script implements this approach:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn import svm

np.random.seed(0)
pos = np.hstack((np.random.randn(20, 1) + 1, np.zeros((20, 1))))
neg = np.hstack((np.random.randn(20, 1) - 1, np.zeros((20, 1))))
X = np.r_[pos, neg]
Y = [0] * 20 + [1] * 20

clf = svm.SVC(kernel='linear')
clf.fit(X, Y)
w = clf.coef_[0]
x_0 = -clf.intercept_[0]/w[0]
margin = w[0]

plt.figure()
x_min, x_max = np.floor(X.min()), np.ceil(X.max())
y_min, y_max = -3, 3
yy = np.linspace(y_min, y_max)
XX, YY = np.mgrid[x_min:x_max:200j, y_min:y_max:200j]
Z = clf.predict(np.c_[XX.ravel(), np.zeros(XX.size)]).reshape(XX.shape)
plt.pcolormesh(XX, YY, Z, cmap=plt.cm.Paired)
plt.plot(x_0*np.ones(shape=yy.shape), yy, 'k-')
plt.plot(x_0*np.ones(shape=yy.shape) - margin, yy, 'k--')
plt.plot(x_0*np.ones(shape=yy.shape) + margin, yy, 'k--')
plt.scatter(pos, np.zeros(shape=pos.shape), s=80, marker='o', facecolors='none')
plt.scatter(neg, np.zeros(shape=neg.shape), s=80, marker='^', facecolors='none')
plt.xlim(x_min, x_max)
plt.ylim(y_min, y_max)
plt.show()
```

Although the code above is self explanatory, here are some tips. `X` dimensions are 40 rows by 2 columns: the values in the first column are random numbers while all the elements of the second column are zeros. In the code, the weight vector **w** = [*w<sub>0</sub>*, 0] and the intercept *b* are `clf_coef_[0]` and `clf.intercept_[0]`, respectively, wehre `clf` if the object returned by `sklearn.svm.SVC`.

And this is the plot you get when the script is run:

[image: Plot of separating hyperplane for one-dimensional data]

For the sake of clarity I'd suggest to tweak the code above by adding/subtracting a small constant to the second feature, for example:

```py
plt.scatter(pos, .3 + np.zeros(shape=pos.shape), ...)
plt.scatter(neg, -.3 + np.zeros(shape=neg.shape), ...)
```

By doing so the visualization is significantly improved since the different classes are shown without overlap.

---

#### Appendix

The separating hyperplane is usually expressed as

[image]

where **x** is a *n*-dimensional vector, **w** is the weight vector and *b* is the bias or intercept. For *n* = 2 we have *w<sub>0</sub>.x* + *w<sub>1</sub>.y* + *b* = 0. After some algebra we obtain *y* = -(*w<sub>0</sub>*/*w<sub>1</sub>*).*x* + (-*b*/*w<sub>1</sub>*). It clearly emerges from this expression that the discriminant hyperplane in a 2D feature space is a line of equation *y* = *a.x* + *y<sub>0</sub>*, where the slope is given by *a* = -*w<sub>0</sub>*/*w<sub>1</sub>* and the y-intercept term is *y<sub>0</sub>* = -*b*/*w<sub>1</sub>*. In SVM, the margin of a separating hyperplane is 2/‖**w**‖, which for 2D reduces to

[image]

Answer (score 1):

the `.coef_` member of `clf` will return the "hyperplane," which, in one dimension, is just a point. Check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23186804/graph-point-on-straight-line-number-line-in-python) for info on how to plot points on a numberline.